# Calculate a Fund

Tags: mutual-funds, investing, index-fund, starting-out-investing, trusts

I did an investment. I am worried I misunderstood everything. I am not worried about the money I was looking to do something risky, but looks like I might have to learn the hard way about doing more research first.

I invested £500 into this:

> https://am.jpmorgan.com/gb/en/asset-management/gim/adv/products/d/jpm-uk-equity-core-fund-e-net-income-gb00b58l4h43

£1,000 into this:

> https://am.jpmorgan.com/gb/en/asset-management/gim/awm/products/d/jpm-asia-fund-a-net-accumulation-gb0030879695

My question is, using previous data how do I calculate my returns?

- UK in 2015/2016 it said 15.18%, so £500 + 15.18% = £575.90. Since this is income would I receive £75.90 since it is the net profit?
- Asia in 2015/2016 it said 41.76%, so would this mean £1,000 + 41.76% = £1,417.60 for that year? But this is accumulation so it is reinvested, meaning next year it will be £1,417.60 then increase/decrease another %?

I was told those high % are actually to do with the Fund's performance as a whole, not the returns I would receive. If that is true how can I calculate my returns?

I feel a bit stupid for believing I could get such high returns, I got very confused I guess... Thank you to anyone that can clarify my mess.

Edit:
I am in UK and using an ISA so it is all tax free. The % above are after tax and other costs associated with the Fund.

Comment: Funds are a scam.  They just advertise the years where they had a high return by luck.  This year they may send you a polite email saying the return  was a loss.

Comment: @JoeBlow that is why you go for GIPS compliant funds which must publish all years' returns or ensure that you have full returns data for any fund in which you invest. Funds are a good way to buy an already diversified strategy if you are not rich enough to efficiently create your own portfolio and are demonstrably NOT a scam. The fact that most fail to beat the market at some point is because of a mathematical certainty; only 50% of things can be better than average.

Comment: Hi MD; GIPS is a good thing; at least in their ads they have to list in the fine print all annual returns.  note that the OP, for example, has been completely scammed by the "Fund concept": so, (A) the OP has seen ads (or something) with figures like "15.18% !!".  Of course (B) these are figures *from a previous year*. What they tell you about this year's performance is: absolutely, completely, totally nothing. Funds are a scam.

Comment: when did you make the investment?

Comment: I don't mind if I lost money. What I want to know is if in 2015/16 I would have got a 15.18% on my investment or not?

Comment: @Joe Blow Some are not scams, I trust the company I posted. It's just I seriously misunderstood how it all works, I blame myself only.

Comment: For the JP Morgan Asia Fund you can get cheaper exposure through iShares AC Asia ex Japan ETF (0.69% annually) vs JP Morgan's 1.5%. JP Morgan's fund looks like what I would call an index hugger, so might as well buy an actual index fund and pay less.

Comment: PS: If you want the money the funds returned you can redeem your shares in the fund and you get your investment + return back. The return they gave you is the change in the amount your shares in the fund are worth plus any cash that they gave you over the year.

Answer (score 6):

A mutual fund's return or yield has nothing to do with what you
**receive** from the mutual fund. The annual percentage
return is simply the percentage
increase (or decrease!) of the value of one share of the mutual fund
from January 1 till December 31. The cash value of any
*distributions* (dividend income, short-term capital gains, 
long-term capital gains) might be reported separately or might
be included in the annual return.

What **you** *receive* from the
mutual fund is the *distributions* which you have the option
of taking in cash (and spending on whatever you like, or
investing elsewhere) or of re-investing into the fund without
ever actually touching the money. Regardless of whether you
take a distribution as cash or re-invest it in the mutual fund,
*that* amount *is* taxable income in most jurisdictions. In the
US, long-term capital gains are taxed at different (lower)
rates than ordinary income, and I believe that long-term capital
gains from mutual funds are not taxed at all in India.
**You are not taxed on the increase in the value of your
investment caused by an increase in the share price over the year
nor do you get deduct the "loss" if the share price declined over
the year.** It is only when you *sell* the mutual fund shares
(back to the mutual fund company) that you have to pay taxes on the capital gains (if you sold
for a higher price) or deduct the
capital loss (if you sold for a lower price) than the purchase
price of the shares. Be aware that different shares in the
sale might have
different purchase prices because they were bought at different
times, and thus have different gains and losses.

So, how do you calculate *your* personal return from the mutual
fund investment? If you have a money management program or a
spreadsheet program, it can calculate your return for you.
If you have online access to your mutual fund account on its
website, it will most likely have a tool called something like
"Personal rate of return" and this will provide you with the same
calculations without your having to type in all the data by hand.
Finally,
If you want to do it personally by hand, I am sure that someone will
soon post an answer writing out the gory details.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is, using previous data how do I calculate my returns?

"Stupid" is the person who does not ask. Better to have visited first, but even asking after the fact will get you an education, at a very low cost.

You would only see those returns had you invested at the beginning of the period advertised. "Past results are not a guarantee of future returns."

Since we have no idea where you are in life, there's little advice I can give you except to invite you to learn. You can easily spend 100 hours on this Stack reading advice on the beginning investor, and every stage after that. We all needed to start somewhere, and in your case, just showing up was a great first step.

Comment: I used the previous year as an example. The previous year it said 15% so does this mean I get 15% interest on the money I invested yes or no?

Comment: No. A 15% gain might mean you own the same number of shares but they are worth 15% more. Or you got 5% in cash, but still the fund is 10% higher. It's a combination of dividends and gain. But, it's never interest.

Comment: Okay. When I login it shows the value of the UK Fund as £570, which is a 14% increase as I started with £500, although this changes every time I log into my account. Pretend after a year the value is £570, do I get sent £70 as a dividend or something similar, or is this only when I sell the Fund back?

Comment: If that's the value, your investment is now worth that. You'd sell if you actually want the money.

Comment: Yes I saw an option to sell the Fund. What I do not understand then is how Net Income and Net Accumulation works, for example how would Net Income pay me if the Fund's value is now £570. If it was Net Accumulation would the whole lot me reinvested for the next few years? Sorry for my questions, these things do not get covered at A-Level education.

Comment: @k1308517 Please, pretty please, look at the **number of shares** that you have and not what your account is worth. If the number of shares is the same as what you purchased, then NO, the Fund **will not** pay you £70 as interest or dividends or whatever. The **only** way to get that £70  is to _sell_ the shares in which case you will "get" £570 and then you need to figure out where to invest the money. **If the number of shares is  more than what you purchased**, then you _already_ "got" some money (and chose to reinvest it in the fund), and the Fund will NOT send you £70 in this case either.